# IDs for localization In-App Purchase

Tags: ios, localization

I'd like to use several languages in my app and will use In-App Purchase. While setting the data about unit have I to register one and the same unit with different languages?
and will it have different IDs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create one product with one ID, and iTunesConnect prompts you to add descriptions in multiple languages.  In your application, when you load the product information, iOS supplies you with the correctly localised information.

Comment: Please, tell me-how many ids in one app I can create? only 10000? or 10000 for one IAP?